# Half vs. a half

Tags: articles, ielts, academic-writing

I'm preparing for academic IELTS by writing some essays and then correcting those using a grammar correction app.

In the following sentence,

> Overall, carbohydrates prevail in both dishes, especially speaking about the second one, which contains more than a half of those.

The app suggests deleting "a" before "half" which results in "...contains more than half of those". But considering the fact that "half" is a countable noun, why there doesn't have to be an article then?

Comment: It is rare that I find myself in agreement with grammar correction software, but this is such a case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that, when half is a noun, it is countable. You can see this because it has a special plural- **halves**.

In this case, though, it's a [quantitative determiner](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners-position-and-order), like **some** and **most**.

---

Note that, when talking about the second of two items that you have already mentioned, you can say "the latter" rather than "the second one". Similarly, you can refer to the first of two items as "the former".